# Error creating the folder

Tags: wordpress, ftp, permissions, directory

There is a site where I get this type of error 
`Error creating the folder wp-content/uploads/noisy. Please create it manually and set the permission to 777 through your FTP client.`

In ftp part I changed the file permissions to 777 but error is still running. 
Also I delete this folder but anyway I get this error.

Comment: you should have permissions in server like folder 755 and files 644

Comment: Can you detail what you mean?

Comment: Also I cant to login admin panel this errors are showing!

Comment: in server if you have to create a folder you should have 755 permission 777 do not works. if you are creating folders using php or wordpress then use mkdir($folderpath, 755);

Comment: I am using wordpress.When I delete following folder uploads or rename it I am still getting this error.

Comment: Please see the following link : http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions . You should also remove the full path from your post, just start the path from /wp-content/... onwards, a setting of 777 is dangerous from a security point.

Comment: try to make all folders and file permissions like 755 and 644.

Comment: Seems it is not working!))All files have 755 permission.What else I can do?

Comment: I have also renamed the plugins folders.I thought that plugin can cause this error but not still getting this error.Very strange thing is that when I delete or rename the uploads folder I am still getting this error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved in at least.

I have added this line to config.php `define('UPLOADS', '/wp-content/uploads');`

All is fine!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:
Go to `Settings->Media` and unchecked the box that says "Organize my uploads into month- and year-based folders". This solves your problem.

Comment: I cant login to admin panel.Getting this errors.How I can do it in other way?

Comment: Ok...

Then can you please add the following lines to the top of your .htaccess file.

<IfModule mod_security.c>
<Files async-upload.php>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</Files>
</IfModule>

Comment: 500 error can be due to the error in the .htaccess file. So if the code added in .htaccess file does not solve the problem just remove it.

Comment: my htaccess look lie this                                                   `<IfModule mod_security.c> <Files async-upload.php> SecFilterEngine Off SecFilterScanPOST Off </Files> </IfModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress `

Comment: The code sounds good. May be any other problem. Just remove the code from .htaccess.

Comment: Ok I have removed but the problem what is I dont understand!

Comment: How can I change wordpress settings->media part in databse.Is there any way?